# Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know there are already many questions asked on this topic and they all have answered. But even though I am trying to implement the answer in my case, it is turning out to be futile.

I am trying to develop an MVC application without using the template. I created a simple web application and then added folders as per MVC template. I have a controller, a model and view for the controller.

In View, I have the following as my first line

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MVCWithoutTemplate.Models.User>"  %>
```

When I am trying to run it, I am getting error as -

> **Description**: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific
> parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message**: Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'.

I tried for the solution i found on various sites. It is as follows -

https://www.codewrecks.com/post/old/2009/04/could-not-load-type-systemwebmvcviewpage/

It is still giving same error.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: are you using razor syntax?

Comment: No. There is nothing inside.

Comment: It is a normal html page whose extension is changed to aspx to make it a view without code behind.

Comment: Has your bin folder a dll System.Web.Mvc ?

Comment: When you updated both the web.config and the views/web.config did you also restart visual studio and reload your solution. The changes to the views/web.config are loaded once at solution start-up and if you change them then you need to make them reload....

Comment: I had not tried it before but now I did, but it is still not working :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh I got it!
I need to update both Web Configs! The one of the entire projects and also the one in the View folder.
I had not updated entire projects web config! My Bad!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out I updated the System.Web.Mvc dll but forgot to set the 'copy local' flag to true. Changing to true fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add view web.config to revelant place in the server. Because sometimes publish can not take view web.config to target publish folder.